# Chrome console <style></style> location

Tags: google-chrome, console

When inspect a website with chrome console, I normally can see where the css is coming from (e.g. test.css:143) but i recently see the following

[image: Console Screenshot]

What does  mean in this case? It is not inline styling neither it is somewhere in the source of the page when I inspect it.

Thank you so much for your help!